# How to get just one location with fused location client?

Tags: android, realm, fusedlocationproviderclient

What I want is to get just one fresh location and remove location updates after getting first location update and add it to realm but the problem am facing is getting more than 100 locations sometimes in a single update and executing 100 transactions in realm crash app

```
public void getCurrentLocation(final Context context) {

    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    final LocationCallback mLocationCallback;
    final FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context);
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(60000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(60000);
    mLocationRequest.setNumUpdates(1);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }


    mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult)
        {
            if (locationResult == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);

            Location tempLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
            if (locationResult.getLocations().size() > 0)
            {
                tempLocation = locationResult.getLocations().get(0);
            }
            if(tempLocation != null )
            {
                RealmManager.writeLocationInRealm(context, tempLocation, true, 0);
            }
        }
    };

    mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this via below code

> This code is in Kotlin

```
private var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient?=null
```

in Your onCreate()

```
fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this@YourActivity)
        fusedLocationClient!!.lastLocation
                .addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? ->
                        //Your lattitude location!!.latitude
                        //Your Longitude location.longitude
                    }
```

Comment: This is code for getting last location and sometimes it doesn't give fresh location so this will not help

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and this is how I solve it in kotlin

```
fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

        locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult)


                if (locationResult.lastLocation != null && locationResult.lastLocation.latitude > 0 && locationResult.lastLocation.longitude > 0) {

                    UserLocationObject.lastLocation = locationResult.lastLocation

                    fusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback)

                }
            }


}
```

Comment: But latitude and or longitude can be < 0 :)